# Datepicker close when clicking on input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using this plugin for datepicker.
https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

What I want to achieve is the following:
- User opens page with datepicker
- User clicks in the textfield / icon of the text input >> datepicker opens
- User clicks again in the textfield >> datepicker closes.

This plugin does have an "autoclose" function, but that does not what I want.
When a user clicks somewhere outside the datepicker popup and the text field, al also closes.

How to make it close also when the input itself is re-clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onChange` event to hide the entire datepicker element.

i.e:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(){
  $('.datepicker').hide();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I mean. I want the datepicker popup to close if i click the text field again. First click on input > open popup. Second click on input > close popup (without date changed)

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable to store if the picker is shown or not:

```
var visible = false;
```

Then change this variable based on the status of the picker (if it's shown or not)

```
$('#datePickerID').datepicker().on('show', function(){
    visible = true;
});

$('#datePickerID').datepicker().on('hide', function(){
    visible = false;
});
```

Then you can hide it (if it is visible) when the user clicks on the input box.

```
$("#datePickerID").click(function(){ 
    if(visible)
    {
      $('#datePickerID').datepicker().hide();
    }
})
```